# Jenkins can't find maven executable

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to configure a simple maven build on Jenkins, but when I run the build jenkins can't find my maven executable.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

    stage 'Clone sources'
    git url: 'https://github.com/user/project.git'

    stage 'Artifactory configuration'
    rtMaven.tool = "Maven-3.5.0"

    stage 'Maven build'
    def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'project/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
    }
```

The error I'm receiving is this:

```
Entering stage Maven build
Proceeding
[Pipeline] ArtifactoryMavenBuild
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.11.0
ERROR: Couldn't find Maven executable.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.model.Run$RunnerAbortedException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.Maven3Builder.getMavenHome(Maven3Builder.java:221)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.Maven3Builder.buildMavenCmdLine(Maven3Builder.java:127)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.Maven3Builder.perform(Maven3Builder.java:97)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:110)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am I missing something?
Maybe a plugin.

Comment: Have you configured the tool? Where you should defined Maven...

Comment: Yes, on global tool configuration, my maven installation is set. Still I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can even look into the `hudson.tasks.Maven.xml` File under your `JENKINS_HOME` directory. 
Sample output:

```
bash-4.2$ cat /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml                                                                                                                                    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>                                                                                                                                                   
<hudson.tasks.Maven_-DescriptorImpl>                                                                                                                                                     
  <installations>                                                                                                                                                                        
    <hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstallation>                                                                                                                                              
      <name>maven</name>                                                                                                                                                                 
      <properties>                                                                                                                                                                       
        <hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>                                                                                                                                             
          <installers>                                                                                                                                                                   
            <hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstaller>                                                                                                                                         
              <id>3.3.9</id>                                                                                                                                                             
            </hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstaller>                                                                                                                                        
          </installers>                                                                                                                                                                  
        </hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>                                                                                                                                            
      </properties>                                                                                                                                                                      
    </hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstallation>                                                                                                                                             
  </installations>
```

The name will be under `hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstallation>name`

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like you specified the wrong name in your pipeline script. You should use the one from your maven tool configuration.